# spring boot batch-- How can we read Jobperameters from ItemReader<>?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

need to fetch the job parameters in ItemReades from jobLancher.run(job, parameters); in to ItemReader<>

Spring Boot------

Comment: No you don't. If you need that you are doing the wrong things.

Answer (score 1):

i did like below.

i created listener where i can monitor after/before batch job running.

in listener i created static method which is return JobExecution entity where as we can find job related parameters like below.

```
public class MyListener extends Job***Listener**{
private static Jobexceution jobExecution1;
@Override
p v beforeJob(Jobexceution jobExecution){
this.jobExecution1=jobExecution;
}
 p s JobExecution getJobExecution (){
  return jobExecution1;
 }
}
```

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: i tried like above mentioned. it is working for me. through the  getJobExecution() method i can able to get parameters(With JobExecution entity) in Reader

Comment: share me if any issues with above scenario, which i answered.